# Enrich soap message with ESQL

Tags: soap, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am creating a simple flow that receives a message via SOAP and in IIB I treat the message with ESQL.

This is my SOAP message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://ComponentesTI">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <com:PushMessageRequest>
     <Message>
      <SerializedContent>?</SerializedContent>
        <HTTPAddress>?</HTTPAddress>
     </Message>
     <Identification>?</Identification>
  </com:PushMessageRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to replicate this message just by changing the Identification field using ESQL (using a GUID)

Something like that:

```
CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot DOMAIN 'XMLNSC';
DECLARE statement REFERENCE TO OutputRoot.XMLNSC;
DECLARE statement2 REFERENCE TO InputRoot.XMLNSC;
SET statement = statement2;
SET statement.PushMessageRequest.Identification = UUIDASCHAR;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use XML namespace in the ESQL syntax.

```
CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot DOMAIN 'XMLNSC';
DECLARE statement REFERENCE TO OutputRoot.XMLNSC;
DECLARE statement2 REFERENCE TO InputRoot.XMLNSC;
SET statement = statement2;

DECLARE com NAMESPACE 'http://ComponentesTI';
SET statement.com:PushMessageRequest.Identification = UUIDASCHAR;
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

The code fragments below take into account the SOAP Envelope.

Copy everything including the Properties folder and any other Header folders and then change the Identification field.

```
SET OutputRoot = InputRoot;
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.*:Envelope.*:Body.*:PushMessageRequest.Message.Identification = UUIDASCHAR;
```

Create a new XMLNSC aggregate with other code handling the Properties folder and other headers as required.

```
CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot DOMAIN 'XMLNSC';
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.*:Envelope.*:Body.*:PushMessageRequest.Message.Identification = UUIDASCHAR;
```

Also depending on whether you are using an HTTPInput vs a SOAPInput Node the top level aggregate may be SOAP rather than XMLNSC.

Lastly as we aren't changing any of the namespaces and are overwriting the value in Identification I used the syntax *****: for the namespace so I didn't have to declare the namespace variables for **soapenv** and **com**